# How to read multiple attributes from an xml file

Tags: c#, linq, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <TestRun id="2fc10ef6-b97f-49e5-a58d-863dfb599cb3" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
   <Times creation="2019-08-26T11:27:34.3642040+00:00" queuing="2019-08-26T11:27:34.3642190+00:00" start="2019-08-26T11:27:29.1640690+00:00" finish="2019-08-26T11:29:28.0320260+00:00" />
   <TestSettings name="default" id="3c3c8ad0-9076-4c83-a283-03f5490f906b">
   <Deployment runDeploymentRoot="_9e3d0007c2b9 2019-08-26 11:27:34" />
   </TestSettings>
  <Results>
   <UnitTestResult testName="FirstName" outcome="Passed" testListId="1">
    <Output>
    </Output>
   </UnitTestResult>
   <UnitTestResult testName="SecondName" outcome="Passed" testListId="2">
    <Output>
    </Output>
   </UnitTestResult>
   <UnitTestResult testName="Thirdname" outcome="Passed" testListId="3">
    <Output>
    </Output>
   </UnitTestResult>
  </Results>
 </TestRun>
```

And i have the following classes:

```
    {
        public string testName { get; set; }
        public string outcome { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public DtoHeader ReadXmlFile()
        {
            var binDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location);
            var file = Path.Combine(binDirectory, "myfile.xml");


            var xDocument = XDocument.Load(file);
            XmlNamespaceManager nameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010");

            var items = xDocument.Root.XPathSelectElements("./ns:Results", nameSpaceManager).ToArray();

            if (!items.Any())
            {

            }
            return new DtoHeader
            {
               testName = items.Descendants().Attributes("testName").First().Value,
            };
        }
```

I will like to extract the value of the attributes testName and outcome and put these values in a list.However, I have not been able to do this after going through multiple examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `items.Descendants().Attributes("testName")` returns `IEnumerable` of `XAttribute`.
2. You need to select the `Value` member of each `XAttibute` and return a list.

   ```
   var list = items.Descendants().Attributes("testName").Select(t => t.Value).ToList();
   ```

**Edit:**

Return as `DtoHeader` List:

```
var list = items.Descendants().Attributes("testName").Select(t => 
                new DtoHeader
                {
                    testName = t.Value
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. This actually works. Do you know how this values can be inserted in the above properties? where : public string testName { get; set; } ??

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of `DtoHeaders` using Linq2Xml you could use the following approach:

```
var headers = xDocument.Root.XPathSelectElements("./ns:Results", nameSpaceManager)
    .Elements()
    .Select(x => new DtoHeader
    {
        testName = x.Attribute("testName").Value,
        outcome = x.Attribute("outcome").Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [xmltocsharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net) to convert the xml to classes and use `XmlSerializer`to do the rest of the job. Here is the simplified code to get the desired result.

```
        string requestBody = ReadFile("XMLFile1.xml");
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestRun));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(requestBody))
        {
            //convert the xml to object
            TestRun testRun = (TestRun)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            foreach (var result in testRun.Results.UnitTestResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{result.TestName} : {result.Outcome}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
var list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DtoHeader>();

foreach (var n in doc.Descendants().First(node => node.Name.LocalName == "Results").Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "UnitTestResult"))
{
    list.Add(new DtoHeader
    {
        outcome = n.Attribute("outcome").Value,
        testName = n.Attribute("testName").Value,
    });
}
```